# WeChat API failing registration in app

Tags: android, wechat

I'm developing an application for the Chinese market which will allow our users to login using WeChat. We have applied for a mobile application on https://open.weixin.qq.com and it passed.

I used the example project of WeChat to see how it works, and got it working fine (WeChatSDK_sample_Android).

Then I tried using our received AppID and have failed since then. When we try to call the register action we see following error pop up in the logcat:

```
Server response error code:404, error:{"ret":-1, "msg":"invalid appkey"}
```

The Package Name in the manifest and the applicationId in our build.gradle file are exactly the same as the package name we put in the wechat form. We first picked the SHA256 signature, but since then also tried the SHA1 and MD5 signature to see if it works (both with and without ':', all in UPPERCASE).

I also tried the chinese application that was referenced multiple times that can be found here https://github.com/mike623/cordova-WeChat-meteor-sharing/blob/master/README.md

I'm completely out of thoughts what I can change now to see if it works.

Here is where I got the appId from (where the blue is now):
[image]

Do you have any idea what I can try, or what I did wrong?

Kr,

Thomas

Answer (score 4):

I also encountered this problem before. It is caused by incorrect Wechat app signature. **Because the signatures of debug and release version are different, so that's why Wechat return**

`Server response error code:404, error:{"ret":-1, "msg":"invalid appkey"}.`

How to solve this problem?

1. Download generate signature tool which is provided by Wechat:
   https://res.wx.qq.com/open/zh_CN/htmledition/res/dev/download/sdk/Gen_Signature_Android2.apk
2. Open the tool in your Android device or simulator, then enter the package name of your app into the tool and get signature:
   [image]
3. At last, check the signature in step 2 with the signature you submitted in the Wechat Open API Platform. If they are different, pls change the signature or build a correct version APK.

Comment: Is there a thing to mention for release? I successfully tested WeChat auth on debug mode and get a signature error on Release mode. An updated signature did not help.